# How high must I raise max_input_var for a WP product filter plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating an e-commerce on WP/WooCommerce and its products have approx. 35 metadata fields (created with [ACF](https://advancedcustomfields.com)) I wish to filter on the shop screen. I bought a [product filter plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/) but once I completed its setup, it just reset and loses all settings. I contacted the owner, who asked me to set `php_value max_input_var 30000`.

The articles I read indicate to raise it to `3k` and my hosting service said `30k` was unusual and I'd have to hire VPS or other dedicated server service to achieve that. I reached out for the plugin owner to get this straight but, as I wait for them to reply, I  asked the hosting guys to raise the setting to 3k and did all the setup again, but 2 min later it was all gone.

Is 30k the right amount? 3k? Here's the [info.php of my site](https://boyflix.com.br/info.php). Let me know if there's any other info you need to evaluate that.

Comment: _What is your current limit? and are you getting failures?_ Start with 3,000, basically all you need to do is test saving your posts where these fields are present to see if you get a critical error on save. You generally get into issues when you have repeater fields with lots of sub fields, and don't add max limits.

Comment: If `max_input_vars` were an issue there would be a Warning issued every time more that the configured number of vars were sent, and any more than that would be ignored. Check your logs to see if this error is present. That said, asking you to set the value to thirty _thousand_ certainly raises a large, bright-red flag to me about the code quality, and I don't necessarily disagree with your host's assessment.

Comment: For clarity, it's like saying "I might post a form with up to 30,000 fields in it", the default is 1000, and even that is pretty high up there.

Comment: Agreed, plus you can always count the fields to see how many are actually being sent in the post data to see if you're even close to the field limit.

Comment: Oh I'm not allowed to rate your replies but here's some thumbs up 
My site's environment is shared and I had to talk to four people to get the `max_input_vars` raised from 1k to 3k and they probably won't raise anymore.

I will perform some tests and luckily come back with more data. Thank you so far!